# OpenIdConnectOptions Missing from .net core sample application on linux

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to follow this tutorial for Azure AD authentication in a .NET core web app:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/aspnetcore2-2

and I get this error:

> The type or namespace name 'OpenIdConnectOptions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am using Linux and have no issue getting the basic templates to generate and build, the issue appears to arise where the tutorial says to add this line:

```
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
});
```

I have tried adding packages (semi randomly) e.g.:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
```

to no avail as the error persists and I get new issues like:

> Error: Package 'Microsoft.Owin 4.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

I am not sure if I am missing some basics with authentication and running .net core on linux, I am new to this and just trying to get the ball rolling with a working demo that actually does something :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not checked on linux yet, but the nuget package you are missing should be produced by ASP.NET Core from the following project: https://github.com/aspnet/AADIntegration. Did you try to update the latest nuget package of ASP.NET Core ?

As a workaround you might want to have a look at the following branch of the sample (which still has the code which was now moved to ASP.NET Core AADIntegration) : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master

Comment: in trying to follow what you suggested i opted for following the clone git repo option instead of run the wizard to create the project, this got to a point that appeared to be a config not code that was my issue but i didn't understand the difference. then i had no time to dig deeper for a few days and when i looked back the tutorials were updated and now working (barring some missing info that was easy enough to find with google). thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Can you please tell us what was missing. Also don't hesitate to look at the PRs for this sample. We are currently working on it.

Answer (score 0):

ran into the same issue. After installing [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLCXA.png) modules, it compiled.

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer in text form instead of linking to images